# Ask about the reason of not giving money to people by banks

Tags: questions, negation, inversion, subject-auxiliary-inversion

Suppose you live in a country, and an economical issue was happened, and the country's banks refuse giving money back to people ... what is the best way to ask about the reason?

1. Why are not banks giving you back your money?
2. Why banks does not give you back your money?
3. Something else ...

And why?

Another question, is my title grammatically correct?

Comment: You want to know why you are not able to **withdraw (your) money** from the bank(s) or why bank accounts have been frozen or why withdrawals have been restricted/limited to certain amounts. Your title might be: WHY HAVE BANK ACCOUNTS BEEN FROZEN?

Comment: Actually I know the reason ... But my problem was, how to ask about the reason correctly, i.e. ask a question grammatically correct.

Comment: **I wish (want/would like) to know why people are not able/permitted to withdraw their money from (the) banks.**

Comment: Ok it is a good answer, but between the choices that I gave in the question, which one is the best ?

Comment: Change your first suggestion slightly to read: Why are banks not giving you back your money? Your second suggestion is not grammatical.

Comment: Ok it is a good answer, but last question, why you must use "to be" (why are banks not ...) instead of using "to go" (why banks do not ...) ?

Comment: It's also possible. **Why do banks not give you back your money?**

Comment: Thank you so much, you did a great work to help me :-)